# Evil spirits from HaShem

Tags: samuel-shmuel-book-of, evil-resha

Within 1 Samuel 16 verses 14, 15, 16, 23 and 18:10, 19:9 etc.. is speaking about a ruach rah, likewise in Judges 9:23 a ruach rah is mentioned of which the verse tells us 'vayishlach Elohim וישלח אלהים , from this verse it seems (at least in many translations of the verse) that this ruach rah was sent by G-d.

1 Samuel 18:10 reads for example, when refering to this ruach rah: vatitzlach ruach Elohim ra'ah el.. ותצלח רוח אלהים רעה אל , in translations refered to as comming upon (and in other times leaving, just as is the case with the ruach Elohim) Saul.

The New International version for example translates the verse from Judges as that HaShem stirred it up.

How should I understand this ruach rah, is it being sent and taken by G-d or is it something from inside people, does it imply both?

Comment: This question would be improved with a citation of one of the relevant verses; especially one that implies that it is "from HaShem".

Comment: @mevaqesh I think that these verses don't say it explicit but because the verse in Judges tells that HaShem send a ruach rah it seems to be the same in the other cases. Still I think HaShem didn't do anything, but that it's because of the kings own emotions, thoughts and actions that this Ruach 'popped-up' as a potential that HaShem established. But I'm not sure..and so my question

Comment: Consider writing the verse in judges.